# Consuming soap web service with an authentication in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, soap

I have followed https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/ and was able to consume soap web service. But wants to consume a secured soap web service from a spring boot application. Can any one help me to find sample application.
Thanks in advance.